# Two identical dbml data context's in one asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, database, linq-to-sql, transfer

I have a separate copy of a sql server2008 database that we used to isolate data. I would now like to bring a few records into the production database from this separate database. I am not sure of the best way to do this, but I need to transfer several tables and ensure the relations remain. The easiest way I think of is to (if possible) create another dbml data context of the separate database and set all variables equal to a new object in the new database. I realized that I am getting many conflict errors. Is there a way to have two databases coexist like this in one application? There a few minor differences in the databases. The production database does have a few added rows.

Thank you for the help,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I'm no authority so perhaps someone can give you a better solution but it seems you can't have two models in the same project with an identical table name. What you could do is create a new project in your solution just to contain the model for the separate database.

This will let you have two models that both contain a "person" object for example because their namespaces will be different. Might help to put using statements at the top of your pages that use both models similar to the below:

```
using PersonLive = MyProject.Person;
using PersonIsolation = AlternateProject.Person;
```